# Dataflow .elementCountAtLeast(1) with .pastEndOfWindow() guarantees

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

If I have a window like this:

```
.apply(Window
    .<String>into(Sessions
        .withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(10)))
    .triggering(AfterWatermark
        .pastEndOfWindow()
        .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))
        .withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))));
```

And it receives 3 elements from Pub/Sub.

Is it guaranteed that the window will trigger exactly 4 times?

Is it guaranteed that there will be:

- exactly one ON_TIME pane (triggered by watermark passing end of window)?
- exactly 3 other panes (EARLY or LATE), exactly 1 per element?

I am looking at [`Timing`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/PaneInfo.Timing) and it says:

> An ON_TIME pane may contain locally late elements. It may even contain only locally late elements. Provided a locally late element finds its way into an ON_TIME pane its lateness becomes unobservable.

So ok, the ON_TIME pane can contain LATE elements, but would another pane be fired by .withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)) for each of those LATE elements in the ON_TIME pane, or those elements would not trigger because they were part of the ON_TIME pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements are only "new" in a single pane. Assuming there are no empty panes, then 3 input elements should lead to at most 3 output panes. With that trigger, there may be an empty ON_TIME pane. You can also ask for an empty final pane by specifying [`ClosingBehavior`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.ClosingBehavior)

If late elements make it into the `ON_TIME` pane, they will not be re-fired as part of a future pane (although they will continue to be incorporated into the result if you are accumulating fired panes).

Comment: Just a clarification - what is `ClosingBehavior` controlling? The ON_TIME pane in this example that is fired before LATE panes or another pane generated after `.withAllowedLateness()` has passed?

Comment: From [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.Unbound#withAllowedLateness-org.joda.time.Duration-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.windowing.Window.ClosingBehavior-) it seems like it is for `.withAllowedLateness()`. If that is the case, can I force having an ON_TIME pane even if there is no new data for it?

Comment: The `ClosingBehavior` controls the final pane (`isFinal` in the `PaneInfo`). The current implementation should guarantee an`ON_TIME` pane since you have an `AfterWatermark` trigger -- whether it is empty depends on how the elements are divided into the speculative and late panes.